# How to add arbitrary content within a user control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Phone App where I would like to achieve the following:
Define a (user)control which has a Button and an arbitrary control. Once the user clicks the Button, the second control becomes visible and the button is hidden.
I can achieve this directly in the CodeBehind or ViewModel but I would like to have some kind of control that I can reuse on all places where I need this.

I googled a bit and come accross the ContentPresenter. 
Control:

```
<StackPanel Background="Red" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Dummy"/>
    <ContentPresenter/>
</StackPanel>
```

XAML call:

```
<controls:MyControl>
   <TextBlock Text="Text Content"/>
</controls:MyControl>
```

But the Contentpresenter cannot be used like this and the Button will never be displayed because the page XAML definition of the content will overwrite the content defined in the user control xaml.

I then found hints to use templates, but I did not yet understand how I could combine this with the logic that I would like to apply here.

Should I create a userControl that has VisibilityProperties for the Button and the other control which are then used by the Template?

Any advice or hint is apprechiated to get an idea where to continue my search.

Comment: Create a custom control as illustrated here: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-wp7-custom-control-in-7-steps. Put your Container, show/hide button, and ContentPresenter in a control template.Then, you can use this MyControl control wherever you please, setting the Content presenter with a custom content template (as in the article)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Control:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="ClickMe" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="Content"/>
</Grid>
```

Control.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Content.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            Content.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            Content.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<local:MyUserControl1 x:Name="MyControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs (adding content):

```
MyControl.Content.Children.Add(new Button());
        MyControl.Content.Children.Add(new Button());
        MyControl.Content.Children.Add(new Button());
        MyControl.Content.Children.Add(new Button());
        MyControl.Content.Children.Add(new Button());
        MyControl.Content.Children.Add(new Button());
```

Comment: This is just a fast method

Comment: The problem here is, you put the Stackpanel with Name "Content" into the control. I wanted to have this outside in the MainPage.xaml as content of my control whereas the button shall be added by the control no matter what content was added in the Mainpage.xaml.